# Event Source getting closed when lock the mobile

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I am using [`universal_html`](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package for `EventSource` and trying to read the data from `EventSource` after lock the phone in **Flutter**, But I am not getting any values because of `EventSource` is closing after **Screen lock.**

```
eventSource = new EventSource(Uri.parse(sseUrl).toString());

      print("getting Eventsource value");
    eventSource.onMessage.listen((event) {

}, onError: (error){
print("on message error");
if(eventSource != null)
{
eventSource.close();
print("event closed");
}
// eventErrorMessage(event.toString(), context);
eventErrorMessage("Connection lost, Please wait for sometime", context);
this.isListening = false;
connectSession();
print(error);

    }, onDone: (){
    print("done");
    },cancelOnError: true);

eventSource.onError.listen((event) {
timerSnackbar?.cancel();
print(event);
// print(event.toString());
if(eventSource != null)
{
eventSource.close();
print("event closed");
}
// eventErrorMessage(event.toString(), context);
eventErrorMessage("Connection lost, Please wait for sometime", context);
this.isListening = false;
connectSession();

    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you more details about `EventSource`, are you using `'dart:html'` for this?

Comment: No, iam using universal_html

Comment: You might be looking for background services.

Comment: Can you format the code and include imports. Also please describe expected output / behavior.

Comment: i tried with background services as well but i don't get the proper solution for that and that function is happend continuously for 5 to 6 hrs.  @yeasin Sheik